# CMake if(DEFINED MY_COMPILE_DEF) does not work. How can I use precompile definition as conditional?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to use a compile definition as a conditional to build a Gtest executable. The problematic CMake code is as follows:

```
add_compile_definitions(TEST_BENCH)
if(DEFINED TEST_BENCH)
  enable_testing()
endif()
```

This does not work though. I've read a few similar questions and answers that have been regarding the use of ${my_var} syntax which is not the case in my code.

Can compile definitions be used in conditionals, and if so how?

Comment: Compile definition is not a cmake variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cmake (cache) variable, which will also allow users to configure your project properly.

```
set(TEST_BENCH OFF CACHE BOOL "Enables testing of your project")
if(TEST_BENCH)
   add_compile_definition(TEST_BENCH)
   enable_testing()
endif()
```

Then the user (and you) can configure your project according to their needs with the help of `ccmake` or `cmake-gui` or with `cmake -DTEST_BENCH=ON`. I believe `target_compile_definitions` is generally preferred over global `add_compile_definitions`.

Still, I wouldn't advise it, you can match `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` variable that is modified by `add_compile_definition` with the `TEST_BENCH` and that way check if the macro is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

In short, add_compile_definitions() is for source files while set() is for CMake variables. if(DEFINED) is to check your CMake or env variables thus you need to use set().
Credit to @squareskittles
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61815468/2324483